# Swift parsing JSON into Table View doesnt work

Tags: json, swift, parsing, uikit, tableview

Hi I have problems to read the Json Data into the TableView.
Can anybody help me, its my first time working with it.
I know I am doing something wrong, but I cant finde the Solution for my JSON File cause in the Internet they use simple ones..

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "title": "Brot",
            "desc":[
                {
                    "Name": "Roggenschrot- und Roggenvollkornbrot",
                    "Menge": "Gramm",
                    "Kalorie": "2",
                    "Energiedichte": "Gelb"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Weizenschrot- und Weizenvollkornbrot",
                    "Menge": "Gramm",
                    "Kalorie": "2",
                    "Energiedichte": "Gelb"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Weizenschrot- und Weizenvollkornbrot",
                    "Menge": "Gramm",
                    "Kalorie": "2",
                    "Energiedichte": "Gelb"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my tableView

```
import UIKit

class EseenTagebuchTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var result: Result?
    var resultItem: ResultItem?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        parseJSON()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return result?.data.count ?? 0
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return result?.data[section].title
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if let result = result {
            return result.data.count
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let text = resultItem?.desc?[indexPath.section].Name?[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = text
        return cell
    }
    

    private func parseJSON() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Ernahrungstagebuch", ofType: "json") else {
            return
        }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        
       
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: jsonData)
            return
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

And here are my Model 1 and after my Model 2

```
import Foundation

struct Result: Codable {
    let data: [ResultItem]
   
}

struct ResultItem: Codable {
    let title: String
    let desc: [descItems]?
}
```

Model 2

```
import Foundation

struct descItems: Codable {
    let Name: String?
    let Menge: String?
    let Kalorie: Int?
    let Energiedichte: String?
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since your json is included in the app bundle it will not change and you have full control of it. So why are the properties optional when they always seem to be present in the json? Perhaps also drop the topmost `data` key if you have no use of it. Is there really an extra comma (,) at the end or is that a typo? Maybe use an online linter to verify the syntax of your json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your json data in your file is not correct, there is an extra "," comma after
the last `"Energiedichte": "Gelb"` , remove that from your file.

Second your model is not correct, you should have:

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let data: [ResultItem]
}

struct ResultItem: Codable {
    let title: String
    let desc: [DescItems]?
}

struct DescItems: Codable {
    let Name: String?
    let Menge: String?
    let Kalorie: String?  // <-- here not Int?
    let Energiedichte: String?
}
```

Using your code `parseJSON()` I was able to parse the data without errors.

EDIT-1: if you really want `kalories` to be `Int`, try:

```
struct DescItems: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let menge: String?
    let kalorie: Int?  // <-- here
    let energiedichte: String?
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        menge = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .menge)
        energiedichte = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .energiedichte)
        let calorie = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .kalorie)  // <-- here
        kalorie = Int(calorie) // <-- here
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
        case menge = "Menge"
        case kalorie = "Kalorie"
        case energiedichte = "Energiedichte"
    }
}
```

Note the change of case, as per common practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! I have a question, when I use the Code from you, how can I rename the Cell name with the Name of the single "Name" of the JSON dishes.
In my case:
 let text = resultItem?.desc?[indexPath.section].Name?[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = text
        return cell

is not working because Error:
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: ha yes, `Name` is now `name`, in my EDIT-1, I changed all `DescItems` to lowercase, as it is the most common practice, and use uppercase for types.

Comment: Yea, when I use lower case Name I get the error subscript(_:)' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, use a String.Index instead.

Comment: `let text = resultItem?.desc?[indexPath.section].name` gives you a String, not an array.
So you cannot have `let text = resultItem?.desc?[indexPath.section].name?[indexPath.row]`.
Just use: `let text = resultItem?.desc?[indexPath.section].name`

Comment: Note, I don't know what you want to display, and since you do not show any other code
I can only guess at what you are trying to display in your table. 
I know that the json data in your file is
parsed correctly with my answer. 
Maybe you can try `let text = resultItem?.desc?[indexPath.row].name`  note the `row` not `section`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use json parse below code:

```
func parseJSON() {
let path =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Ernahrungstagebuch", ofType: "json")
let jsonData = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try! (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary)!

if let data = jsonResult["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    self.arrPlan = data.map{Day(JSON: $0)!}
    //            print(arrPlan)
    
}
```

}

Try to this code for get data array object and after reload tableview Data.

Comment: Use native Swift types instead of NS… types and why move away from using Codable?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, it is default.

Comment: Not sure what you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **extension** to ***parse json***.

```
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from file: String, dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate, keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy

        do {
            return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to missing key '\(key.stringValue)' not found – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to type mismatch – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let type, let context) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle due to missing \(type) value – \(context.debugDescription)")
        } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(_) {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle because it appears to be invalid JSON")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

*And use it like this:*

```
let incomingData = Bundle.main.decode([Your_Model].self, from: "Your_Json_File_name.json")
```